# multiple programs can't use the internet simultaneously on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

I just bought a new Dell laptop with Windows 10 installed.  I can connect to my wifi without any trouble, but I can't actively use it with multiple programs at once.  For example, if I have a [Putty](https://www.putty.org) session open and try to do something in chrome, it shows me the dinosaur page.  If I wait a few seconds and refresh, chrome works, but Putty stops working - either my session dies or it freezes for a few seconds.  The same thing happens with Skype and Windows Update.  I don't think there's a hard limit on how many programs can use the internet, but if one program is using it another program is less likely to be successful.  This even happens between two Putty windows.

This is not a problem with the network, because it doesn't happen on any other computer (including my old laptop, which was also Windows 10).

I also don't think it's a bandwidth problem with my computer's connection to the network.  Downloading the initial updates and programs wasn't noticeably slow, and high quality skype video calls work fine.  And the issue happens even between windows of Putty, which isn't what I would call an intense network user.

Has anyone seen this before?

I can edit in details about the computer if you let me know what's relevant.

Comment: You have had this problem since you got the laptop I presume?

Comment: @Ramhound yes, which was 2 days ago

Comment: It seems like your bandwidth is not enough. Or maybe some software occupy too much bandwidth. How much bandwidth do you have on your network？ Try some bandwidth monitoring software to check whether some software occupy too much bandwidth. If not, maybe you need to improve your bandwidth.

Comment: @Peter.G I explained in the question why this seems unlikely to me.  And see the edit which provides a little more information.

Comment: Do you have any kind of security software installed (e.g. Firewall, Antivirus, ...)? If so, could you try to disable those and try again?

Comment: Does it work over ethernet? And on another WiFi network (phone hotspot?)? Do you have the latest drivers installed?

In any case you would be able to go back to the store with this issue, since it sounds like something that'd be covered under warranty and may not be worth your time/effort if they can do it for you (free of charge that is).

Comment: @Paul I spent an hour on the phone with Dell yesterday and it seems to be fixed.  I'll write an answer with more details once I'm more confident that the problem is completely gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent an hour on the phone with Dell.  The technician activated remote assist and did several things, including updating the drivers, clearing the DNS cache, and deleting some preinstalled apps that are known to cause trouble.  Over the next few days, I tried again and the problem was not fixed.

Then I spoke with Dell again (different technician this time).  He suggested reinstalling the operating system, but this requires a flash drive, which I didn't have.  At this point I had a strong suspicion that the problem was caused by faulty hardware and didn't want to wait the extra time it would take to buy (or have Dell send me) a flash drive, get Dell on the phone again, and have them walk me through the procedure.  I just asked for a replacement, which was granted with no further questions asked.

I tend to think that the technician wasn't so confident that reinstalling the operating system would work, or he most likely would have pushed harder for me to try that.

Bottom line: at least in my case, this was almost definitely a hardware issue.